# Will Int value R.string.app_name Change If Restart App Or something Else

Tags: android, string, notifications

As title says, I suspect my R.string.app_name changed. Since my notification sometimes never update any more, but code below did executed (I can see it in logcat). Is that possible?

```
    nm.notify(R.string.app_name, notification);
    Log.i(TAG, "B:showNotification(): id = " + R.string.app_name);
```

Comment: Are you asking if the ID has changed, or if the string itself has changed?

Comment: I am asking the ID, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible as all `R.*.*` resources are defined as constants in your `R.java` file (in the `/gen/<your-package>` folder). These are not edited by Android later on.

Example:

```
public final class R {
    public static final class anim {
        public static final int accelerate_interpolator=0x7f040000;
        public static final int activity_slide_in=0x7f040001;
        public static final int activity_slide_out=0x7f040002;
    }
    public static final class attr {
    }
    public static final class drawable {
        public static final int ic_action_search=0x7f020000;
        public static final int ic_launcher=0x7f020001;
    }
    public static final class id {
        public static final int main_layout=0x7f070001;
        public static final int scroll=0x7f070000;
    }
    public static final class layout {
        public static final int main=0x7f030000;
    }
    public static final class string {
        public static final int app_name=0x7f050000;
    }
    public static final class style {
        public static final int AppTheme=0x7f060000;
    }
}
```

This is the R.java file from one of my real projects. As you can see, each value is a `final int` which is assigned when you're developing the app (all values are assigned using hex, so you'd have to use an online converter to the actual int value)

Comment: Anyway the values could be changed if new resources are added before compile time right? So a hardcoded value on the app should be checked after each resource modification

Comment: Yes, that is possible. But if you're using the `R.*.*` to reference the value, this shouldn't be a problem. if you're hardcoding it, it could be a problem.

Comment: But it's really unlikely for someone to use the hard coded value, and I think this is not the case in the question...hehe

Comment: Yeah.  His code show's that he is referencing using the names in R. The problem is likely somewhere else in his code.

Comment: Year, It did not change though it is not recommended. something wrong with my receiver.